# How to create books for Kindle Fire that allows for panning and zooming similar to Newsstand?

Tags: epub, kindle-fire

To be clear, this *is* a programming question. I want to publish a book for the Kindle Fire that has images that can be pinched, panned and zoomed in the same manner as the content for the Newsstand does. I have researched this a lot, and can't find any information on how to do this, but there is a lot of information on how to do other things.

- There are fixed layout samples that show how to do "comic-style" image overlays, that do not allow for panning and zooming.
- There are samples that show using the `<img>` tag, which allows you to double tap into an image viewing mode of sorts, that allows pinching, panning, and zooming, but you have to tap an "X" to  get out of that image mode to continue reading.
- However, for magazine content, ie. the stuff that you buy from the "Newsstand" (almost all, and I can provide a video sample if need be), are navigable the way I would like my book to be. You can view a whole page, pinch to zoom in, pinch to zoom out, pan, and swipe to go to the next page.

It is likely that this is impossible for "books," and it is only possible if you have a magazaine publishing contract with Amazon, (and it uses a different format), but I am having a difficult time ascertaining that for sure from any source. I've searched and asked on the fora there with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the magazines are a different format... and that's the difference. KF8 is HTML and doesn't let you pinch & zoom.

Comment: The fact that KF8 is HTML doesn't actually imply that you can't pinch and zoom. Also, KF8 is not HTML, it's a set of specs that are actually extensions of ePub, as detailed [here](http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf). However, I do think you're right, and you can't do what i am looking to do.

Comment: KF8 is most certainly HTML. Open an epub file, it's almost all HTML. The spec you linked to shows a lot of HTML. Perhaps I should disclose that for a while I worked on KF8 at Amz :) Sorry I'm not providing more specifics, I tried to find something public I could use to explain my answer but couldn't find it :/

Comment: Thanks! As far as you know, are there any options for publishing content that displays the way magazines do (pinching & zooming, graphical page scrubbing) to the Kindle Fire as books? I'd like to publish comics and I think the magazine style of image displaying is vastly superior to the way Amazon wants to handle comics- the lightbox/ "comic- style" image overlays. how does one publish a magazine? - perhaps that's the direction I should look into? Any advice would be appreciated.